# Unable to cast object of type DataTable to type System.IConvertible

Tags: c#, oracle10g

I've inherited an application which I'm struggling to troubleshoot. I'm not sure if this is the best way to have written the application and I would have done it differently, but I don't want to have to re-write it.

The application has Oracle 10g as it's background db. It appears that my predecessor is sending two date parameters and formating them as System.Datetime (YYYY/MM/DD HH24:mm:ss). I think this might be the problem, but I'm not 100% certain. I've checked the NLS_DATE_FORMAT of the db and it's DD/MON/RR HH24:MI:SS and I'm thinking the error might because the wrong date format is being used to query the db. I would appreciate some help in solving this if possible.

```
int totalcount = System.Convert.ToInt32(adapter.GetValues(myStartDate, myStartDate.AddHours(1)));
```

//Code in Designer.cs - stepping through it by disabling 'Just my code'

```
public virtual Mytable.MytableDataTable GetValues(System.DateTime startDate, System.DateTime endDate) {
    this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[2];
    this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[0].Value = ((System.DateTime)(startDate));
    this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value = ((System.DateTime)(endDate));
    Mytable.MytableDataTable tdataTable = new Mytable.MytableDataTable(); *<<--- when I use the visualizer to view tdataTable, there's nothing in the table. This then throws the above titled error message.*

    this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
    return dataTable;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Created and ran a test and the test failed with the following message:
'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Error in the stack trace:

```
        public void BookClub_BeforePrintTest()
    {
        BookClub_Accessor target = new BookClub_Accessor(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        object sender = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        PrintEventArgs e = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        target.BookClub_BeforePrint(sender, e);
        Assert.Inconclusive("A method that does not return a value cannot be verified.");
    }
```

Comment: When you say "This then throws the above titled error message" - *what* throws that exception? Please post the stack trace of the exception. Additionally, you say you're "formatting" parameters as System.DateTime (YYYY/MM/DD HH24:mm:ss) - as you're providing the values as `DateTime`, you're not providing them in a text format at all.

Comment: Thanks Jon for the reply. I mean tdataTable contains no results and  the error in the subject of my post is thrown on the line that calls the method (int totalcount...) With regards to the date, I mean I see it formatted as 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:mm:ss'.

Answer (score 0):

In your method you are returning datatable and then you try to convert it to int. You just can't do that. If your adapter fills data table with only one value(scalar) you can go with something like this

> return (int)dataTable.Rows[0][0];